# How To T-mobile Web Day Pass on Non T-Mobile Device?

Tags: nexus-one, t-mobile, data-plan

I have a Pay As You Go SIM card on my Nexus One which works great for voice calls but I don't really know how to use it for T-mobile's $1.49 Web Day Pass.

I called T-Mobile's customer support but they were clueless... All they could say was "press the `web2go` button".

I don't have a `web2go` button on my Nexus One.

I know [it is possible](http://androidforums.com/t-mobile/206126-prepaid-daypass.html#post1814416) to use T-mobile's $1.49 Web Day Pass on a Nexus One, but I don't know how.

Any help would be appreciated.

UPDATE: Thanks to the link posted by @uTubeFan I was able to find http://m.web2go.com/myaccount/summary.do which seems to give some home but for now all I am receiving is:

```
Error 500--Internet Server Error   
From RFC 2068 Hypertext Transfer Protocol -- HTTP/1.1:    
10.5.1 500 Internal Server Error    
The server encountered an unexpected condition which 
prevented it from fulfilling the request.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may want to read [this blog post](http://blog.wapreview.com/8077/). You might get a way with simply trying to access any web site and waiting for the `Buy Web DayPass` prompt.

Otherwise you might need to do the trick mentioned in the blog, which is trying the above on a non-Android phone and then swapping the the DayPass enabled SIM.

Comment: Thanks + 1. I tried to just access any web site and wait for the `Buy Web DayPass prompt`. I could see the `EDGE connected` and even `EDGE in use` status icons at the top of my screen, but I never received any prompt from T-Mobile. After very long wait all I received was an "Unable to connect to server" dialog.

Comment: Interestingly, I could even see `GPRS connected` for a few seconds but then it was replaced by `EDGE in use` and never came back.

Comment: It finally worked! No need to swap SIM cards between phones, all I had to do is access http://m.web2go.com in a location where the phone displays full 4 bars.